# How to create a HTTP Request in Telnet

Tags: sockets, http, powershell, http-headers, http-request

I am interested in scripting a HTTP Request to a listening web service I wrote (for testing purposes). I want to do this in Powershell. Initiating a HTTP Request through telnet is easy enough.

```
telnet google.com 80
```

Then, after a socket is established I can type in the following HTTP Verb and file:

`GET /search?q=test`

This is equivalent to performing a google search for the word "test". Great! However, I need to provide a more detailed HTTP Request Header if I want to do something more interesting.  I'm trying to do something very similar to the example found here: http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/http-notes/making-http-requests-via-telnet

Following the author's example from the previous site, I created a local file with the following contents:

```
echo "open $1 $2"
sleep 2
echo "GET $4 HTTP/1.0"
echo "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4"
echo "Host: $3"
echo
echo
sleep 2
```

(This is similar to the custom HTTP Request Header I'd like to use for testing my own web services)

I then save this file as "getpage" (I also tried saving it as "getpage.sh").  I continue following the author's example and attempt to pipe the previous file into telnet from Powershell:

```
./getpage tonycode.com 80 tonycode.com /| telnet
```

However, Powershell is returning the following error:

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: ~\Desktop\getpage.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./getpage tonycode.com 80 tonycode.com /| telnet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (~....Desktop\getpage:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantActivateDocumentInPipeline
```

I typed $PSVersionTable in Powershell and verified I'm using Powershell version 4.0.  I'm starting to run out of ideas. I looked through the StackOverflow forums regarding http requests through telnet but I haven't found a good way to send a custom HTTP Request Header through telnet by passing in a pre-formated http header via a shell pipe.  I can't really type the entire Http Request in telnet because 1) that defeats the purpose of scripting these kinds of things and 2) pressing the Enter key from telnet submits the current request before I can finishing typing the full Http Header.  Does anyone have any suggestions how I can accomplish this in PowerShell?  I can already write and send custom Http Headers in Firefox and it makes life way easier.  I would just like to script this in Powershell if possible.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'a', 'b' |ForEach-Object {$PSItem}

Comment: PS... and if you dont insist on using the telnet client, there are tons of exaples of making "raw" HTTP requests with System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interested in scripting a HTTP Request to a listening web service I wrote (for testing purposes). I want to do this in Powershell.

then leave telnet alone :)

PowerShell(v3+) has built-in cmdlets:

- [Invoke-WebReques](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)
- [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx)

Or you can use *System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient*

- [Replacing Telnet.exe (now removed from Vista)](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/08/30/replacing-telnet-exe-now-removed-from-vista/)
- [Scripting Network / TCP Connections in PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/10/28/scripting-network-tcp-connections-in-powershell/)

Or *System.Net.WebClient*

- [More advanced HTTP scripting: Facebook Photo Album Downloader](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/09/04/more-advanced-http-scripting-facebook-photo-album-downloader/)

PS:

[image: Lee Holmes in action :D]

Comment: Thank you for all the recommendations. I'll certainly try some of these alternatives. I really wanted to do this the old fashioned way, mainly for learning purposes, but it appears I may need to get with the times and use a better client.

Comment: well i find it a bit hard to find my way in the Lee Holmse's script but it's more or less what you're trying to achieve with telnet ...gonna paste a screenshot

Comment: This is great!  Now if I could just script the entire thing so I don't have to type the Http Request manually each time.

Comment: I think I'm going to try making a C# console application using a TcpClient as an alternative approach at this. I'll ultimately have more control over that than trying to do this with PowerShell, although it was a neat experiment. Thanks again for all your input.

Comment: btw i keep referring to TcpClient while i actually mean Socket.

Answer (score 1):

Using `telnet` to talk `HTTP` might have been "cool" in the past. But no one should be doing it nowadays. Especially when anything more than a trivial `GET` is required.

You should be using a real library for this like `libcurl` or whatever is available in your development environment.

Notes:

- HTTP/1.0 is blocked by many sites nowadays. You should probably use HTTP/1.1.
- HTTP/2 is a binary protocol. Using `telnet` or whatever "text" method you might have read about is just not possible with this protocol.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Honestly, I've been writing a lot of client server applications lately and I've learned a lot about sockets so I find telnet fascinating.   Although I agree there is a more appropriate way to go about this in modern times.